# Trying to populate an empty list in a combo box but getting attribute error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tkinter, combobox

```
def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

         self.teams = list()
```

I have a combobox that i need to populate with data from a website, I'm trying to make an empty list with self.teams = list() at top of my code , and then I have a web_teams_finder function for the get the datas from website and adding them into a self.teams list.

```
def web_teams_finder(self):

    ......

    for lines in web_words:
       self.teams.append(lines)
```

```
   #output of  list after running web_teams_finder function ["teams a" , "team b", "team c" ]
```

but i am getting an attribute error:

*AttributeError: 'Application' object has no attribute 'teams'*

and this the combobox code:

```
def side_parts_of_ui(self):

     self.combobox = ttk.Combobox(self.bottom_side, values= self.teams , width=22) 
     self.combobox.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan= 2)
```

ERROR:

```
self.combobox = ttk.Combobox(self.bottom_side, values= self.teams , width=22) 
AttributeError: 'Application' object has no attribute 'teams'
```

Comment: have you tried `self.teams = []` instead of `self.teams = list()`?

Comment: yes , i got the same error.

Comment: Are you initializing it in the constructor (the `__init__(self)` method)?

Comment: my list under the `def __init__(self, master):` but Combobox is in the inside of a function.

Comment: can you post a minimal working example with the error?

Comment: @SNNDMNSZ: May i see the output of `print(type(self))` just before `self.teams = list()`

Comment: @stovfl     <class '__main__.Application'>

Comment: @SNNDMNSZ ***`<class 'main.Application'>`***: Then you must delete `self.teams` somewhere before. Fulfill the request from @jpnadas about [mcve]

Comment: show minimal working code which we could run to see problem.

Comment: The only explanation is that you're trying to access the `teams` attribute before you've initialized it. That, or you've deleted the attribute after initializing it but before trying to use it.